# System.Net.WebClient DownloadFile not making HTTP Request

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient

I am working on an application which is supposed to download a file at a given URL to a path. I used the code shown below which I have seen in many places.

I am using fiddler to monitor my connections and to troubleshoot, and I am running into an issue where Fiddler never requests the path, and I never get an error thrown (no Message box shows up).  I have set it up so I display a message box BEFORE entering this function and that works perfectly, but it appears to get stuck in this function. No error is thrown, it just seems to hang.

```
Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String, ByVal _SaveAs As String)
    Try
        Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
        ' Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.
        _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs)
    Catch _Exception As Exception
        'Error
        MsgBox("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Does anybody have any thoughts as to why this may be happening?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that this is only happening on a test computer running SERVER 2012. It works fine on my Windows 7 Development Machine

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the code and work out exactly which line is 'hanging', just so we are certain. From your post it sounds like the `_WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAS)` line is hanging. *EDIT* posted before your edit, so this is now irrelevant.

Comment: Nope, just made an edit to the question, this is running on my test machine which doesn't have visual studio installed on it, so no way of doing a break point

Comment: You could setup a remote debug, but for something basic like this I would try other steps first. EG: Can you download the file through a web browser, or is something on the server blocking this?

Comment: Yup, I am able to access the files through a standard browser. I'm currently trying another method to download them as I am not set on using webclient, so any other suggestion for file downloading to path is accepted. If the way I am hoping for works, I'll update this

EDIT: I got it working using the tutorial [HERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bfarley/simple-web-file-download-in-vb-net/) 

I'm new to SO, should I delete the question? answer it myself? or let somebody else answer?

Comment: Answer it yourself with the link. P.S link doesn't work for me.

Comment: What didn't work about it?

Comment: Nevermind, seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully resolve the issue as to what is wrong with the WebClient, but I managed to solve this using a tutorial found [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bfarley/simple-web-file-download-in-vb-net/).  There is one thing different in newer .NET versions than the tutorial and that is just changing

```
WebRequestFactory.Create
```

to be

```
WebRequest.Create
```